# Express.js routing: how to prevent reloading of previous page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, routes

I am new to express (or web development in general) and have a question about routing.
I am creating a web app on Firebase with pure JS, and am using routing on Firebase cloud functions. The routing part looks like below. The purpose is, when URL is  in the form of /xxxxxx, it sends the profile html page, and when URL is for of r/xxxxx, it sends the posts html page. Then client-side rendering will be done to populate the additional data to make up a page. Below is the part of the code:

```
exports.webAPI = functions.https.onRequest(app);
    app.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
        res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=86400, s-maxage=86400');
        res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/app/profile.html'));
    });
    app.get('/r/:post', (req, res) => {
        res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=86400, s-maxage=86400');
        res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/app/post.html'));
    });
```

The issue is: whenever the user clicks on a post and then goes back to the profile page, the whole page is re-rendered. This is understandably very bad for user experience in the world of modern web app.

The question: how do I prevent reloading of previous page, unless there is a meaningful change to it(e.g. new post uploaded?)? Is there a way to do it in Express? 
If there is a better version of code to do this, let me know . If I need to look at certain parts of the documentation, please advise. Or, if this is not possible with Express and I should look at something else, do guide me on where to look at.
Thanks!

Comment: If you're just trying to send data to your server or get data from the server without rendering anything in the client or changing the current page, then send the data with Javascript using an Ajax call instead of by clicking on a link.

Answer (score 0):

Install axios package. In my scenario i am trying to register a form. So this all things i need to do for register without refreshing the page.

```
const register = async (name, email, password, passwordConfirm) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: "your url",
            data: {
                name,
                email,
                password,
                passwordConfirm
            }
        });
        console.log(res);
        if (res.data.status === "success") {
            alert("You are registered succesfully");
            window.setTimeout(() => {
                location.assign("/");
            }, 1500);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error.response.data.message);
        console.log(error);
    }
};

document.querySelector("#registerform").addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    const passwordConfirm = document.getElementById("confirmPassword")
    .value;
    register(name, email, password, passwordConfirm);
});
```

Note: e.preventdefault plays major role.